# Get automatically the appropriate CustomLayout in PPT

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am still beginner in VBA. I have an existing ppt presentation.
I would like to load a Template and to match automatically the slide with the appropriate layaout depending on what it contains (image and/or text and/or title).

I am doing it manually right now.

```
Sub test21()
Call LoadDesign

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(3)
ActivePresentation.Slides(2).CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(7)
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(3)

End Sub

Sub LoadDesign()
    ActivePresentation.Designs.Load TemplateName:="C:\myTemplateFile.pot", Index:=1
End Sub
```

I am using VS2008 and mso2010.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can use this snippet to start with and add more conditions based on your needs:

```
Sub SelectSlideLayout(ByVal slideNumber As Integer)
    Dim hasTitle  As Boolean
    Dim hasPicture As Boolean
    Dim hasSubtitle As Boolean
    Dim sh As Shape

    hasTitle = False
    hasPicture = False
    hasSubtitle = False

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(slideNumber)

        For Each sh In .Shapes
            If sh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderCenterTitle Then
                hasTitle = True
            ElseIf sh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderTitle Then
                hasTitle = True
            ElseIf sh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderSubtitle Then
                hasSubtitle = True
            ElseIf sh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderPicture Then
                hasPicture = True
            ElseIf sh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBitmap Then
                hasPicture = True
            ElseIf sh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderObject Then
                hasPicture = True
            Else
                '' TODO: Specify more cases
            End If
        Next sh

    End With

    If hasTitle And hasSubtitle Then
        ActivePresentation.Slides(slideNumber).CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1)
    ElseIf hasTitle And hasPicture Then
        ActivePresentation.Slides(slideNumber).CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2)
    Else
        '' TODO: Specify more cases

        'Default layout
        ActivePresentation.Slides(slideNumber).CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I was expecting a method that handle everything automatically because this is a very used functionality.
I was trying your solution, it worked so far. I have just to delete some empty placeholder before the Selection.
Thanks bro/sis!